# I want to fit the video to the screen

Tags: html, css, html5-video, live-streaming

I want to fit the video to the screen and scrolling needs to be disabled.

**Problem:** 
Instead of being full screen it is overflowing from the screen.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <style>
    .videosize {
position:absolute;
z-index:-1;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
height:auto;
}
</style>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/indigo-player@1/lib/indigo-player.js"></script>
</head>

  <body>
    <div id="playerContainer" class="videosize">
    <script>
      const config = {
        sources: [
          {
            type: 'hls',
            src: 'https://test-streams.mux.dev/x36xhzz/x36xhzz.m3u8',
          }
        ],
      };

      const element = document.getElementById('playerContainer');
      const player = IndigoPlayer.init(element, config);
          </script>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the `<body>` element have a class where
`position: relative` , `width: 100%` and `overflow: hidden` are declared or use the inline `style="..."`

After doing this the video should take the width of the parent with a relative position.

Comment: I tried this but didn't work. I am a beginner so maybe i am doing something wrong.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: try to change the `.videosize` position to `position: relative` or `absolute`

Answer (score 1):

**The solution can be this:**

- Added position:fixed; in css
- Added height:100%; in css
- Added background: url('https://test-streams.mux.dev/x36xhzz/x36xhzz.m3u8') no-repeat center center; in css
- Added background-size: 100%; in css

**Know Issues**

- NavigationUI visible only in full screen mode (F11 or F) given of the script (Need to change the script to fix these) but it still work.

**Final Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
    .videosize {
    position:fixed;
    z-index:-1;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background: url('https://test-streams.mux.dev/x36xhzz/x36xhzz.m3u8') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 100%;
    }
    </style>  
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="playerContainer" class="videosize">
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/indigo-player@1/lib/indigo-player.js"></script>

 <script>
      const config = {
        sources: [
          {
            type: 'hls',
            src: 'https://test-streams.mux.dev/x36xhzz/x36xhzz.m3u8',
          }
        ],
      };

      const element = document.getElementById('playerContainer');
      const player = IndigoPlayer.init(element, config);
          </script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If it helps please give me the right answer check.

Comment: Also I wonder if making the Div itself have a 100% size (width/height) then the player would also stretch to fit the screen? That would avoid the extra work in the CSS part.

Comment: It's works as you said but i need to control buttons so i can not use this. Thank you so much anyway.